# Is `iss` property in JWT tokens redundant?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

I'm reading up on some OpenID Connect documentation trying to get my head around the protocol. I came across the issuer property that is common in the JWT tokens. How come this is required if we should always check the signature of the token against the expected endpoint?

I understand that one can validate against either a symmetric or asymmetric hash, but validation is expected either way.

Have I missed an important feature of the JWT?

Answer (score 2):

Think of the Issuer as kind of a namespace. Your subject, which identifies the principal, usually has some kind of id. If the id is simply an autoincrement integer from a database, it will most likely be not unique if you accept JWT from different issuers within one application.

Have a look at [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-9), where states uder 4.1.2: *The subject value MUST either be scoped to be locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.*

```
4.1.1.  "iss" (Issuer) Claim

   The "iss" (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the
   JWT.  The processing of this claim is generally application specific.
   The "iss" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
   value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

4.1.2.  "sub" (Subject) Claim

   The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
   subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
   about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
   locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.
   The processing of this claim is generally application specific.  The
   "sub" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
   value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.
```

Comment: Ah, this makes so much more sense then. However I'm curious, how come services like Auth0 and similar usually prefix the sub with `auth0|<user id>`? Wont this replicate the point of using `iss`?